# Excel Addins Version auto Update

Tags: office-js, office-addins, visual-studio-2022, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

Is there any way to auto-increment version number of Excel Add-ins when ever I publish a newer version using Visual Studio 2022, just like auto-increment for click once apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Visual Studio (nor Office web add-ins extensibility model) doesn't provide anything for that out of the box. However, in Visual Studio you may consider using post-build events like shown on the screenshot where you could replace/update numbers programmatically on your own:

[image: post-build actions in visual studio 2022 for office web add-ins]